# Column pressure control in distillation

Tags: distillation

In the industry , it's important to maintain the column pressure control in the distillation column .

" Pressure alterations will alter column vapour loads and temperature profiles. .
So when using Temperature control as a substitute for composition control, pressure compensation is essential to achieve a desired composition . "

"Pressure variations change relative volatiles and affect fractionation process.  " 
From this , I understand that if pressure acting upwards on the vapour is lesser than the pressure acting downwards , then it will affect the fractionation process.

But I do not understand the top part - 
"
" Pressure alterations will alter column vapour loads and temperature profiles. .
So when using Temperature control as a substitute for composition control, pressure compensation is essential to achieve a desired composition . "

Why does it link to temperature ? And in conclusion , I'm confused about how pressure is maintained in the distillation column and for what for .

Comment: things heat up when you apply pressure to them and cool down when you reduce pressure; I suggest that you take a look at the ideal gas law

Comment: The most common way to vary pressure in distillation is with a vacuum pump.